# Google Play services out of date. Requires 12800000 but found 8703448

Tags: android, google-play-services

My app uses the following dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
```

It connects to the Google Api to get device location and to store data in Google Smart Lock notably.

It works fine except on one device running on Android 6. 
When trying to connect to the Google Api, I get the following error:

> ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED
>
> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires
>   12800000 but found 8703448

I can't move back to a previous version of play-services lib because Android Studio says

> ERROR: All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0

What should I do so that the app can run on device with an out of date version of Google Play services ?

Comment: You can show dialogue box to update the google play services @matdev

Comment: How to do that ? No other option ?

Comment: I have implemented a Google sign in my app using firebase. The users who have not updated the google play services are unable to sign in with Google. So I researched about this and I got the only option is making user update the play version. My question if firebase is not allowing the sign In we have no choices left unless we update the app @matdev

Comment: Have you checked in root level 'build.gradle' file?

Comment: Thanks @g.brahma Datta How to get the version number of Google Play Services installed ? If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Sure i have an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the error by updating the Google play services version using this code,

```
            //On button click of the google signIn 

             googleSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent,GOOGLE_SIGNIN_ID);
            }


    //onActivity Result code.
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
  data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGNIN_ID){
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> googleSignInAccountTask = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {

            GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = googleSignInAccountTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
            fireBaseAuthenticationWithGoogle(googleSignInAccount);

        }catch (ApiException e){

            //if user doesn't have updated google play services version

            if (e.getStatusCode() == 12500){

                try{
                    // show your own AlertDialog for example:
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    // set the message
                    builder.setMessage("This app uses google play services for signing in")
                            .setTitle("Do you want to update?");

                    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", (dialog, id) -> {

                        //final String appPackageName = "com.google.android.gms";
                        final String appPackageName = "com.google.android.gms&hl=en_IN";
                        try {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                        }catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }catch (Exception err){
                    err.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

put this where you got the exception. I hope it helps @matdev.

Comment: Could you please include the code where you query the API to know the version of Google Play Services installed ?

Comment: I got the error 12500 which is because of not updating the latest play services version. After researching about it I got to know the play services version was updated after I wrote the code I updated the play services version and able to login to the app. This is the similar issue what you asked @matdev

Comment: You can write this code where you got the exception @matdev

Comment: You can find out the installed version of GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES using GooglePlayServicesUtil.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION_CODE

Comment: yes but you can't track every time what is the updated version when it is in production.If that is the point you can keep the condition if the app google play version is less than the updated version then use the code which i have posted @matdev

Comment: Yes I tried, GooglePlayServicesUtil.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION_CODE returns the installed version of Google Play Services

Comment: so you can put this dialog box when it doesn't match the installed version with updated version @matdev

Comment: You can also upvote so that it reaches many people @matdev.Thank you.